# AutoMapper "needs to have constructor with 0 args or only optional args" when mapping class to record

Tags: .net, automapper

I have a mapping configuration that defines mapping from an AccessToken database entity to an AccessTokenResponseDto like this:

```
            CreateMap<AccessToken, AccessTokenResponseDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ExpiryDate,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ExpiryDate.ToShortDateString("yyyy-MM-dd")))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Token,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value));
```

And my `AccessToken.cs` and `AccessTokenResponseDto.cs` look like this:

```
    public class AccessTokens
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

```
       public record AccessTokenResponseDto (int Id, string Token, string ExpiryDate, string FriendlyName);
```

Then in my application I retrieve all AccessTokens for a user and attempt to map them to the response dto like this:

```
            var tokens = _dbContext.AccessTokens
                .Where(token => token.UserId == _user.Id)
                .ToList();

            var mappedTokens = _autoMapper.Map<List<AccessTokenResponseDto>>(tokens);
```

However this gives me the following error:

[image]

I am not sure how to approach this problem. Other places in my code I map from a record to another record and this works just fine, so I am not sure if the problem is due to mapping from a class to a record? Or if it has something to do with some of the property names/types not matching, but I would think that the configuration in the `CreateMap` method would handle this (e.g. mapping from `src.Value` to `dest.Token` and formatting `ExpiryDate` to a string). I also tried using `DisableCtorValidation()`, but it still gave the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: You need `ForCtorParam`.

Comment: `DisableConstructorMapping` also works.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/discussions/3609

Comment: @RafaelHerscovici unfortunately, the GitHub issue does not talk about any solutions.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use `ConstructUsing` if you want to keep using `AutoMapper` and well defined `records`.

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html?highlight=ConstructUsing#custom-destination-type-constructors

> Note: Personally I think that often AutoMapper is more in the way than
> that it is helping you, consider using something else or do a custom
> construction/mapping, it's fairly easy now that you have the record.